# RxUI - is it better to create a listener per transaction or on the stream processing object?

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Over the past 3-4 months, I am finding that, by default or just coincidence, all of my RxUI observables (.Subscribe) are created within the various objects' Constructor (code). However, the app also makes considerable use of background tasks that monitor various streams and take actions (update UI, create transactions, etc) and, on occasions, these tasks need to abort certain transactions. So, I am just wondering where is the best 'place' to instantiate a 'listener' for the abort instruction (flag)? Within the transaction object when it's created or within the 'supervising' object that's monitoring the stream? If within the transaction, what are the implications for performance and disposal? I know that this is a rather broad question but am hoping that someone might be able recommend an appropriate pattern. Any pointers, comments appreciated.

Please see the mock-up code below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

using ReactiveUI;

using UserSettingsClassLibrary;

namespace fxR.UTILITIES.MockCode
{
    public class MockRxUI_AbortTransaction : ReactiveObject { } // ignore this class

    public class ManageTransactions : ReactiveObject
    {
        // properties
        CancellationTokenSource ctTransactionPosition;

        // constructor
        public ManageTransactions()
        {
            // initialise
            ctTransactionPosition = new CancellationTokenSource();
        }

        // methods
        public async Task OpenTransaction(MyStreamProcessingObject sPO, string user, string openTransactionAction)
        {
            // ... create transaction object, db log, etc

            // open a 'listener' in case this Transaction is aborted
            if (user.Contains("/"))
            {
                sPO.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ActiveObject.AbortTrade)
                    .Log(this, "TransactionOpen -> Abort trigger ")
                    .Subscribe(abort =>
                    {
                        if (sPO.ActiveObject.TradeOpen && abort)
                        {
                            // abort
                        }
                    });
            }
        }
    }

    // the OpenTransaction method above would be called from elsewhere in the app, eg
    public class SomeOtherObject : ReactiveObject
    {
        ManageTransactions _manageTransactions;
        MyStreamProcessingObject _sPO;

        public SomeOtherObject(MyStreamProcessingObject sPO)
        {
            _sPO = sPO;
            _manageTransactions = new ManageTransactions();
        }

        public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
        {
            await _manageTransactions.OpenTransaction(_sPO, Environment.UserName + "/" + GetType().Name, "TransactionAction").ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    // ================================================================================================
    // OR, open a 'listener' on the Stream Processing Object when it is constructed (first initialised)
    // ================================================================================================

    public class MyStreamProcessingObject : ReactiveObject
    {
        // object properties
        private ActiveObject _activeObject;
        public ActiveObject ActiveObject
        {
            get { return _activeObject; }
            set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _activeObject, value); }
        }

        // constructor
        public MyStreamProcessingObject()
        {
            // listen for Transaction abort status
            this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.ActiveObject.AbortTrade)
                .Log(this, "Log -> ActiveObject.AbortTransaction")
                .Subscribe(async abort =>
                {
                    if (abort)
                    {
                        await Task.Run(async () => await AbortOpenAutoTransaction().ConfigureAwait(false));
                    }
                });
        }

        // methods
        private async Task AbortOpenAutoTransaction()
        {
            var ok = false;
            // await some abort code, if all ok, set ok = true;
            if (ok) ActiveObject.AbortTrade = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You have declared the `OpenTransaction` is async and returns type `Task` yet you have no `await` calls or return statements. As well the Subscribe call is obviously leaking IDisposables. Bad code from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you some advice with regards to subscriptions and disposables in the precence of `async/await`. You can use the following pattern.

```
async Task<int> Foo(IObservable<bool> observable, Task<int> task){

    var subscription = observable.Subscribe
        ( x => Console.WriteLine("WhooHoo");

    using(subscription)
    {
        var value = await task;
        return value + 10;
    }   
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
async Task<int> Foo(IObservable<bool> observable, Task<int> task){

    var subscription = observable.Subscribe
        ( x => Console.WriteLine("WhooHoo");

    try
    {
        var value = await task;
        return value + 10;
    }finally{
        subscription.Dispose();
    } 
}
```

The subscription will be disposed when the task is completed.

If however you find you are creating subscriptions in a constructor then you need another pattern.

```
public class Foo : ReactiveObject, IDisposable {
   private CompositeDisposable _Cleanup = new CompositeDisposable();

   public Foo(IObservable<int> observable){
       var subscription = observable
            .Subscribe(x=>Console.WriteLine("WhooHoo"));
       _Cleanup.Add(subscription);     

   }

   public void Dispose(){
       _Cleanup.Dispose();
   }
}
```

or better using the RXUI extension method [DisposeWith](http://reactiveui.net/api/index.html?%2Fapi%2Fpages%2FSystem.Reactive.Disposables.DisposableMixins.DisposeWith(T).html)

```
public class Foo : ReactiveObject, IDisposable {
   private CompositeDisposable _Cleanup = new CompositeDisposable();

   public Foo(IObservable<int> observable){
       observable
            .Subscribe(x=>Console.WriteLine("WhooHoo"))
            .DisposeWith(_Cleanup);
   }

   public void Dispose(){
       _Cleanup.Dispose();
   }
}
```

normally I create a base class

```
public class DisposableReactiveObject : ReactiveObject, IDisposable {
   protected CompositeDisposable Cleanup { get; } = new CompositeDisposable;
   public void Dispose(){
       _Cleanup.Dispose();
   }
}
```

and then can use it as

```
public class Foo : DisposableReactiveObject {
   public Foo(IObservable<int> observable){

       observable
            .Subscribe(x=>Console.WriteLine("WhooHoo"))
            .DisposeWith(Cleanup);

   }
}
```

Comment: your recommended pattern looks good and i'll use it to improve my code. One question, in my example, the StreamProcessingObject remains open until closed by the user or when the App is exited, so does this need to implement Dispose for each observable? Presumably garbage collect will deal with them?

Comment: Any time you call Subscribe you get an IDisposable which you must decide how to handle. Garbage collection __does not__ dispose them ever. Either use a __using__ statement or store them in a field for later disposal. There is no cheating allowed. ( Also if you like the answer please mark it as accepted )

Comment: In your case `StreamProcessingObject` should implement `IDisposable` or `DisposableReactiveObject` and collect all subscriptions to be disposed of in the pattern I have suggested.